# Copy cell value if length is < 10 into the last string of cell value above VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I've imported a text file into excel what happens is some texts had break into the next line i.e

```
ColumnA
--------------
1313 Disneyland Dr, Anaheim, CA 92802
, USA  '<---Copy/Cut cell value into the last string above cell
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United
States '<---Copy/Cut cell value into the last string above cell
```

desired output

```
ColumnA
--------------
1313 Disneyland Dr, Anaheim, CA 92802, USA
1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043 United States
```

I've come up with this code but I'm lost in copying it in the last cell value

```
Sub CutCopyValue()
Dim Last As Long
Dim i As Long
   Last = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For i = Last To 1 Step -1
        If Len(Cells(i, "A").Value) < 10 Then
            Cells(i, "A").Copy // I got lost in the destination
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Every help is appreciated!

Comment: Rather than copying just set the previous cell value to itself plus the cell below `Cells(i -1, 1)  = Cells(i - 1, 1) & " "  & Cells(i, 1)`

Comment: Also be aware this you're running this for every line, if you need to move every other cell change to `Step -2`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @TimWilkinson you are great :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't make it using `.Copy`, simply use string concatenation with `&` :

```
Sub CutCopyValue()
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim DatSheet As Worksheet
Set DatSheet = ActiveSheet
With DatSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        If Len(.Cells(i, "A").Value) < 10 Then
            .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value = .Cells(i - 1, "A").Value & .Cells(i, "A").Value
        End If
    Next i
End With 'DatSheet
End Sub
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks @R3uK :D

Comment: @Anne : Glad I could help! ;)